# How can I tune the set of items shown to me by Google News?

Tags: google-news

I have a local news section (for Seattle, WA, if it matters) set up on my Google News homepage. Most days, all it shows me is sports news, however, which do not interest me at all. I want to somehow downvote the sports news so that things that might actually interest me will bubble to the top.

How can I convince Google News that I don't care about sports?

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can!

1. "Personalize"
2. Find (or add) the "Sports" topic
3. Drag the slider to the left to where it says "Rarely"

Comment: Unfortunately, they got rid of this option.